# Xamarin Unknown errors while building

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a problem. When I try to compile my xamarin app, I get the following 4 errors:

> 1.) Duplicate 'global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlFilePathAttribute' attribute MyApp
>   C:\Users\alex\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\RegisterPage.xaml.g.cs
>
> 2.) Type 'MainPage' already defines a member called 'InitializeComponent' with the same parameter types
>
> 3.) The "FilterAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\alex\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\MyApp.dll'.
>   File name: 'C:\Users\alex\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\MyApp.dll'
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FilterAssemblies.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() MyApp.Android
>
> 4.) Metadata file 'C:\Users\alex\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\MyApp.dll' could not be found    MyApp.iOS   C:\Users\alex\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.iOS\CSC

I'm just started  with the app, so I haven't done much so far. The only thing I have done is created 2 content pages with axml.

Here is my RegisterPage.axml:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MyApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class RegisterPage : ContentPage
    {
        public RegisterPage()
        {
            lblSignInAddRecognizer();
        }

        void lblSignInAddRecognizer()
        {
            lblSignIn.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer()
            {
                Command = new Command(() =>
                {
                    DisplayAlert("Task", "Clicked it!", "OK");
                })
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my MainPage:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: It seems that you rewrite the method  `InitializeComponent()` in MainPage . You can provide the code and xaml of `MainPage` and  `RegisterPage` .

Comment: Code is in the question now. I have already deleted the InitializeComponent() from the code, but still the same error!

Comment: I have recreated this project and coppied the axml code back to the new one, then I get the same errors!? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Delete the folder bin and obj ,then clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: I already figured it out. It was a copy/paste mistake in the axml. I had the x:class the same for both pages

Comment: You can post the answer and accept it , which will help more people .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO get this marked as the answer... .in your XAML File update

```
         <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="SOLTUION_NAME.PAGE_NAME">
```

TO SOLUTION_NAME to your solution's name
and PAGE_NAME to your xaml's name.

This helped me.